# Disable auto audio playing in webView

Tags: ios, webview

I have a simple links that opens in WebView in my app. When i open some link, start auto playing audio file. How to disable him? or stop? When i stop him via tap on "stop button" he stops, but when i tap on back button he did't back...

My simple code, but it's not in it

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_linkString]];
[_linkWebView loadRequest:request];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

}

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

[MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

}

Maybe i need JavaScript? and `evaluateWithJavaScript` ? Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need inject a piece of javascript to do this.

if you have jquery, you can easily select all video tag, then remove its autoplay attribute.

try

```
$('video').attr('autoplay', false)
```

if you do not have jquery, try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')
```